# AccessViolation in WPF with no user code on the stack

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm getting a strange `AccessViolationException` in a WPF application. Since there is no user code on the stack I'm not really sure how to go about troubleshooting this. It also only happens every 2-3 days which adds to the troubleshooting complexity.

```
at MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods+MILUnknown.Release(IntPtr)
at MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods+MILUnknown.ReleaseInterface(IntPtr ByRef)
at System.Windows.Media.SafeMILHandle.ReleaseHandle()
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSourceSafeMILHandle.ReleaseHandle()
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()
```

My image manipulation code (slightly simplified)

```cs
private int timerCount;
private void TimerProc() // called from a timer obviously
{
    if(Interlocked.Increment(ref timerCount) !=0)
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref timerCount);
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        byte[] img = FetchImageFromExternalSource(); //returns a jpeg image
        this.Image = LoadImage(new MemoryStream(img));
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref timerCount);
    }
}

private BitmapImage LoadImage(Stream inputStream)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = inputStream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    bitmapImage.Freeze();
    return bitmapImage;
}

private BitmapImage image;
public BitmapImage Image
{
    get
    {
        return image;
    }
    set
    {
        if (image!= value)
        {
            this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
            {
                image = value;
                PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Image"));
            }),null);
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice on if I'm hitting a known bug (.NET 4) or if there is some problem with the code that I've missed would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of timer, specifically?

Comment: @Pete System.Threading.Timer

Comment: Do you have any logging in your application that can help isolate when / how it is occurring other than just the error?  If you can't track it down you may need to resort to a tool like WinDBG (Windows Debugging Tools) to find the issue.

Comment: You cannot implement a lock with the Interlocked class.  Use a proper synchronization object, like Monitor or Semaphore.

Comment: @HansPassant locking in a timer callback is not a good idea.  I guess you could use `Monitor.TryEnter` but I don't see how that is any better than using Interlocked the way I have. Access to the bound property value and PropertyChanged event only happen on the UI thread so locking shouldn't be required there either.

Answer (score 0):

System.Threading.Timer invokes the callback on a background thread, *not* on the UI thread, which the BitmapImage class is probably expecting. Try using [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Comment: This shouldn't matter because the image gets frozen prior to being passed off to the UI thread (otherwise there would be Cross Thread Exceptions as soon as the UI thread tried to read the image) still might be worth a shot though.